# checking columns in 2 tables and saving 2 columns in 3rd table if 7 columns match

Tags: php, mysql

I am putting together a site for a competition.

In the user end I have a table (selections) with the following columns

> Date, User Name, Pick 1, Pick 2, Pick 3, Pick 4, Pick 5 and Pick 6

In the admin end I have a table (results) with the following columns

> Date, Pick 1, Pick 2, Pick 3, Pick 4, Pick 5, Pick 6

What I want to do is check that the dates and all 6 picks match on both tables and provided all match, save the Date and Username from Table (selections) to a third table. I know I can use joins but not sure how to create a select for 2 columns or create the joins for multiple columns.

What would be the easiest way to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor schema design. Consider revising that.

Comment: can you please upvote the answers, Strawberry downvoted you have enough reputation for that thx

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If there are alway six pictures you can do this

```
INSERT INTO selections SELECT a.Date, a.UserName 
                       FROM admin a INNER JOIN results r ON a.Date = r.Date 
                       AND a.Pick1 = r.Pick1  AND a.Pick2 = r.Pick2 AND a.Pick3 = r.Pick3 
                       AND a.Pick4 = r.Pick4 AND a.Pick5 = r.Pick5 AND a.Pick6 = r.Pick6
```

you need of curse rewrite the column names to your actual design

Answer (score -1):

The same names allows to use NATURAL JOIN:

```sql
INSERT INTO third_table (`date`, username)
SELECT `date`, UserName 
FROM selections
NATURAL JOIN results
```